# How to accurately adjust KDE plasma panel height?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, panel, plasma

I can just drag it. But when I drag it I don't know the height of it in pixels. How could I adjust it accurately so that i know the height?

Comment: [KRuler](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/kruler/) ? Might not work as it might not go behind the panel...

Comment: I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but I think I have a good answer for it:

Go to `~/.config/plasmashellrc`
the attribute name you are looking for is "thickness"

There you can specify for example `thickness=64`

Log out and log in back again to see changes.

If you have changed the resolution, there will be a section specifying the panel values for each used resolution, so to see changes you will have to change the one that corresponds to your current resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [KRuler](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/kruler/) - it looks like this:

[image: kruler]